# How to convert java object xml file to xml file using c# or any tool?

Tags: java, c#, xml

`source xml` file is `java object xml`

```
input file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
<object class="MyMessage">
  <object class="RequestMessage">
    <field name="language">
      <null/>
    </field>
 <field name="messageId">
      <value class="java.lang.String">85036585</value>
    </field>    
    </object>
</object>
```

I want to convert above all structure into normal xml structure using c# or is there any tool to do?

expected xml output -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
    <MyMessage>
      <RequestMessage>
        <language>
        </language>
     <messageId>
          85036585
        </messageId>    
        </RequestMessage>
    </MyMessage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the code below will work in every case, but it does work with your posted xml.  I'm using a recursive algorithm using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.Unicode);
            reader.ReadLine(); //skip xml identification due to unicode not being recognized.
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            XElement root = doc.Root;

            string xmlHeader = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\" standalone=\"yes\"?><{0}></{0}>", (string)root.Attributes().FirstOrDefault());

            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlHeader);
            XElement newRoot = newDoc.Root;
            RecursiveParse(root, newRoot);
        }
        static void RecursiveParse(XElement parent, XElement newParent)
        {
            List<XElement> children = parent.Elements().ToList();
            if (children != null)
            {
                foreach (XElement child in children)
                {

                    if (child.Name.LocalName != "null")
                    {
                        string innerTag = (string)(XElement)child.FirstNode;
                        XElement newChild = new XElement((string)child.Attributes().FirstOrDefault());
                        newParent.Add(newChild);

                        if (innerTag != "")
                        {
                            newParent.Add(innerTag);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            RecursiveParse(child, newChild);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional information: Root element is missing.

Comment: What are you calling root element?   I'm getting all tags.

Comment: I'm getting this error while executing program.

Comment: I need to know more info on error.  It work with sample code so you must be using a different xml file.  I said I wasn't sure if code will work with every input file.  It is hard with a sample of one set of inputs to get code working.  Need more samples.

Comment: this line gives me error -             `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);`


An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Root element is missing.

Comment: The xml file cannot start with spaces.  The code is skipping first line so I suspect there is some spaces in the file.  The code works with posted xml.